# code to close a matlab app

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, exit

I have written a Matlab app with the app designer tool, and have successfully coded everything except the pesky (and most likely simple) exit button. The button itself should do what it says, close the app when clicked, but looking online has just led me to dead ends. Here is what I have written down for the exit function; it doesn't work, but its better than writing no code:

```
 % Button pushed function: ExitButton
    function ExitButtonPushed(app, event)
        Figurename = app.UIFigure ;
        close Figurename
    end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MATLAB interprets `close Figurename` as `close('Figurename')`, which is not a valid object to close. See [command syntax vs. function syntax](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/syntax.html)

Use `close(Figurename)`, or really just `close(app.UIFigure)`.

Answer (score 3):

writing

```
close all force ;
```

seemed to do the trick; as it closes all processes in the Matlab code that were running, which works perfectly for what I want.

Comment: That's a sledgehammer solution - use the method described by @excaza instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
%Draw EXIT push button refer to exitFcn function
uicontrol(handles(1),'Style','PushButton','Units','normalized',...
    'Position',[0.8158 0.05 0.1 0.1],...
    'String','Exit',...
    'Callback',@ButtonexitFcn);

return;
%---------------------------------------------------------------------
function ButtonexitFcn(varargin)
%This function close all figures and terminate program
    close all;
return;
```